# Content type Not Set JSON Object from Server Spring

Tags: java, json, unit-testing, rest, spring-mvc

I have set up a REST application in spring, I would like the applicaiton to return JSON object from my Java Classes. I trying get my unit test to recognise the response as a JSON object but it keeps failing.

here is the application context

```xml
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.livingsoup.beaconapp"/>

    <!--<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder" />-->

    <!-- mvc names pace is to set annotation driven set up check name space and classes-->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>


    <bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json"/>
    </bean>



    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database"/>
        <property name="username" value="user"/>
        <property name="password" value="password"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.livingsoup.beaconapp.data.entities.CustomerEntity</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
       <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="customerDOA" class="com.livingsoup.beaconapp.data.services.CustomerDOAImpl"/>

</beans>
```

here is the web.xml file

```xml
<web-app version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Beacon MVC Rest App</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

this is my controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/student")
public class DataController
{
    private CustomerDOA customerDOA;

    @Autowired
    public DataController(CustomerDOA customerDOA)
    {
        this.customerDOA = customerDOA;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    Student getData()
    {
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setName("Hello World");
        return student;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/findByPhoneNumber", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody CustomerEntity findByPhoneNumber()
    {
        return customerDOA.findByPhoneNumber("07966487189");
    }
```

and here is my Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Customer", schema = "", catalog = "iBeaconServiceDB")
public class CustomerEntity
{
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String address1;
    private String address2;
    private String address3;
    private String city;
    private String postCode;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 255)
    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 255)
    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName)
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "phone_number", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 25)
    public String getPhoneNumber()
    {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber)
    {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "address_1", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 255)
    public String getAddress1()
    {
        return address1;
    }

    public void setAddress1(String address1)
    {
        this.address1 = address1;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "address_2", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 255)
    public String getAddress2()
    {
        return address2;
    }

    public void setAddress2(String address2)
    {
        this.address2 = address2;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "address_3", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 255)
    public String getAddress3()
    {
        return address3;
    }

    public void setAddress3(String address3)
    {
        this.address3 = address3;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "city", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 255)
    public String getCity()
    {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city)
    {
        this.city = city;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "post_code", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 255)
    public String getPostCode()
    {
        return postCode;
    }

    public void setPostCode(String postCode)
    {
        this.postCode = postCode;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        CustomerEntity that = (CustomerEntity) o;

        if (id != that.id) return false;
        if (address1 != null ? !address1.equals(that.address1) : that.address1 != null) return false;
        if (address2 != null ? !address2.equals(that.address2) : that.address2 != null) return false;
        if (address3 != null ? !address3.equals(that.address3) : that.address3 != null) return false;
        if (city != null ? !city.equals(that.city) : that.city != null) return false;
        if (firstName != null ? !firstName.equals(that.firstName) : that.firstName != null) return false;
        if (lastName != null ? !lastName.equals(that.lastName) : that.lastName != null) return false;
        if (phoneNumber != null ? !phoneNumber.equals(that.phoneNumber) : that.phoneNumber != null) return false;
        if (postCode != null ? !postCode.equals(that.postCode) : that.postCode != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        int result = id;
        result = 31 * result + (firstName != null ? firstName.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (lastName != null ? lastName.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (phoneNumber != null ? phoneNumber.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (address1 != null ? address1.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (address2 != null ? address2.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (address3 != null ? address3.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (city != null ? city.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (postCode != null ? postCode.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

this is my unit test

```
 public void testGetData() throws Exception
    {
        CustomerDOA customerDOA = mock(CustomerDOAImpl.class);
        DataController controller = new DataController(customerDOA);

        MockMvc mockMvc = standaloneSetup(controller).build();
        mockMvc.perform(get("/student/findByPhoneNumber"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"));
    }
```

this is the error i am getting from my unit test

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Content type not set
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:39)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertTrue(AssertionErrors.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.ContentResultMatchers$1.match(ContentResultMatchers.java:80)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:153)
    at com.livingsoup.beaconapp.controllers.DataControllerTest.testGetData(DataControllerTest.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

this is the response that prints out from my unit test, I cant understand what I am doing wrong. Why will my unit test not recognise my JSON output?

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
         HTTP Method = GET
         Request URI = /student/findByPhoneNumber
          Parameters = {}
             Headers = {}

             Handler:
                Type = com.livingsoup.beaconapp.controllers.DataController
              Method = public com.livingsoup.beaconapp.data.entities.CustomerEntity com.livingsoup.beaconapp.controllers.DataController.findByPhoneNumber()

               Async:
   Was async started = false
        Async result = null

  Resolved Exception:
                Type = null

        ModelAndView:
           View name = null
                View = null
               Model = null

            FlashMap:

MockHttpServletResponse:
              Status = 200
       Error message = null
             Headers = {}
        Content type = null
                Body = 
       Forwarded URL = null
      Redirected URL = null
             Cookies = []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I'm seeing your configuration looks ok.

But you are missing the Accept header, I'm not sure spring-mvc needs this header set to set the content type. But you can definitely configure spring to ignore the accept header.

```
contentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean.setIgnoreAcceptHeader()
```

It's worth a try or just set the header.

```
mockMvc.perform(get('/..').accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

Comment: I have set the header in the test and it will display in the output, content type is still not set. Where do i add contentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean.setIgnoreAcceptHeader()? I am very new to spring

Comment: You set it as a property of the bean:     <bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">

Comment: Just saw that your Body was also empty which indicates that nothing has been serialized at all. Do you have jackson-mapper-asl in your classpath ?

Comment: I have now set the property on the contentNegotiationManager and i have added the depedancy jackson-mapper-asl 1.9.13 to my pom.xml file. but no joy

Comment: Should i init hibernate in the setup method of my test class

Comment: What happens if you return an object directly in your controller instead of calling your dao ?

Comment: when i create a test object and return that it seems to work. Also when tested in a browser it works as well. I don't think i have set up hibernate correctly in my unit test. I will keep investigating. But thank you for your help Jonas Geiregat

Comment: That's it! You need to make sure your DAO actually returns an object in your controller from within your test. That means indeed initializing hibernate and make sure there is some kind of data present when you run your test!

Answer (score 1):

I was setting up my testing Class incorrectly, I failed to add the Annotations at the top of my test class, Also I was should have added the @AutoWired Annotation to the  the controller and i also added the doSetup method (see example below)

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration("file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml")
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true, transactionManager = "txManager")
public class DataControllerTest extends TestCase
{

    @Autowired
    CustomerController dataController;

    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void doSetup()
    {
        mockMvc = standaloneSetup(dataController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetDataParam() throws Exception
    {
        String phoneNumber = "5551234";

        mockMvc.perform(get("/customer/findByPhoneNumber/" + phoneNumber))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)).andDo(print())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.firstName").value("Russell"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.lastName").value("Milburn"));
    }
}
```